# Javascript Array is getting turned into a string when passed into a function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have some code in google apps scripts. I've created a web app connected to a spreadsheet. In the html, I have this button

```
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="updateButton(data);"
```

That the user can click. When they click it, it turns the updateButton function. data is a two dimensional array defined earlier in the js code, and I know it can be called by elements and has type object. However, when I try to use it inside update button, its type is string and it comes out as a comma separated string. Since the array is two dimensional, I can't just use split as this make it one long array instead of a two dimensional one.

For example, if originally data is

```
[["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["9", "8", "7", "6"]]
```

It ends up after as

```
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6"
```

Comment: Please add complete code

Comment: `when I try to use it inside update button, its type is string` - you're probably doing something wrong in that case

Comment: Rather than adding the complete code, create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a two dimensional array to one dimensional array, you can use array method **`flat`**, but this not support all browser.

Another way you need to use for loop

```
let currentArray = [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["9", "8", "7", "6"]]
let newArray = []
currentArray.forEach(rowItem=>{
    rowItem.forEach(columnItem=>{
        newArray.push(columnItem)
    })
})
```

I hope that the answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I found the issue. My data array is coming from google apps scripts, and I'm trying to write it to javascript. I have this line as part of my templated html.

```
  <script>
      var data = <?= data ?>;
  </script>
```

Since the template evaluates the data, it seems to be passing a string version of data (inside the template) to the data inside javascript. So I'll have to find another way to pass that data variable to javascript.

Comment: Use asynchronous HTMLService calls - i.e. `google.script.run`. Review the best practices for `HtmlService` for examples.